# College 529 plan and state taxes

Tags: united-states, taxes, state-income-tax, 529-plan

I live in PA, do you know if I enroll in 529 plan before the end of the year and contribute some amount, will I get State tax refund in 2014?

I usually owe 0$ on state taxes. I understand if I owed some amount, some of it could be written off because of state deduction. But if you owe nothing do you get a credit instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't pay state taxes at all, I don't believe you can get a refund (actually "refund" is probably not the right word).

However, if you pay state taxes but don't owe money when it comes time to file, any additional deductions/credits will result in your having overpaid, which means you can get that money refunded.

Comment: In general you have to contribute to a 529 plan associated with your state.

Comment: In tax lingo, the word *refundable* means that for a given tax credit, it may very well dial back to money the government owes you, beyond what you paid. I agree, that for PA, the refund is just that, refund only, not refundable, as it's not a credit, just a deduction.